# C - For loop doing a simple operation, doesn't increment counter

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk

I'm writing a program that will play Mancala. This program includes GTK and two threads - I don't believe either of those two are the problem.

Basically what is happening is I have an array of this data structure:

```
typedef struct puds{
    int x;
    int y;
    int count;
    int flag;}PUDPOINT;
```

Easily, x and y coordinate, number of stones, and rather it is the computer or user's flag (0 or 1).

I create a thread using these lines:

```
pthread_mutex_init(&mut, 0);
pthread_create(&thid, 0, (void *) movecomputer, win);
```

Which runs this function:

```
void *movecomputer(GtkWidget *win){

        int tmp;
        int flagcopy;
        int rndmove;
        for(;;){
                sleep(2);

                pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
                flagcopy = thread_flag;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);

                if(flagcopy == COMP_MOVE){
                        sleep(1);
                        printf("Its comp's move\n");
                        /* Here is where the AI logic goes */
                        look_for_comp_move();

                        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
                        thread_flag = USER_MOVE;
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
                }
                else{
                        printf("Its user's move\n");
                }
        }
}

void look_for_comp_move(){

        PUDPOINT fauxpuddles[TOTAL_HOLES];
        int i, k;

        fprintf(stderr, "THERE SOME STUFF GOIN DOWN\n");
        /* For indexes 8-13 */
        for(i = 8; i <= TOTAL_HOLES; i++){
                /* If there are stones to move, copy the board*/
                if(puddles[i].count){
                        for(k = 0; k <= TOTAL_HOLES; k++){
                                fauxpuddles[k].x = fauxpuddles[k].x; // Don't care about X or Y
                                fauxpuddles[k].y = fauxpuddles[k].y;
                                fauxpuddles[k].count = puddles[k].count;
                                fauxpuddles[k].flag = puddles[k].flag;
                        }
                        //copyboard(fauxpuddles);
                }
                fprintf(stderr, "i:%d\n", i);
        }
        return;
}
```

Which spirals into an infinite loop. After trying a `fprintf` statement in the innermost(k) loop, It appears as k only goes from 5-12. Copying the board was in the copyboard function, but was moved up until I can figure out why this isn't working.

Does anyone know why this problem is occurring? I believe I have provided the relevant information. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of `TOTAL_HOLES`?

Comment: 13, sorry - forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C arrays are zero-based so valid indices for

```
PUDPOINT fauxpuddles[TOTAL_HOLES];
```

are [0..TOTAL_HOLES-1].  Your loop

```
for(k = 0; k <= TOTAL_HOLES; k++){
```

runs past this.  The final iteration, when `k==TOTAL_HOLES` writes beyond the end of memory allocated by `fauxpuddles`.  The effects of doing this are undefined but it sounds like you're writing to the memory used one of the loop counters - `i` and `k`.

The fix is simple, either perform one fewer iteration of the loop

```
for(k = 0; k < TOTAL_HOLES; k++){
```

or add an extra element to `fauxpuddles`

```
PUDPOINT fauxpuddles[TOTAL_HOLES+1];
```

Comment: Thank you. I was having extreme tunnel vision and was sure it had to be related to the threading. This is my first program using threads, and I've used many loops before, just never realized that. Thank you!